# how to run a function when finish an interpolation with tween.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

I have an array called `mesh` that contains 10 meshes.

```
console.log(mesh.length) //-> 10;
```

I would like to tween them to change their scale. I assign a scale for each of them. I create a `for` loop and use the library tween.js  :

```
for (var i in mesh){
  new TWEEN.Tween(mesh[i].scale).to({ x: 4, y: 4 },  1000).start();
}
```

I need to know how to run a function when all tweens end. For example, I need show:

```
console.log('all interpolations are completed');
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you look for is `tween.onComplete(onCompleteCallback)`.

In your example you could write :

```
new TWEEN.Tween(mesh[i].scale)
    .to({ x: 4, y: 4 },  1000)
    .onComplete(function(){
        //your callback
        })
    .start();
```

EDIT : in your project, inside a loop where all the tweens have the same duration and if the `onComplete` callback is the same, no need to call it 10 times. Instead :

```
//inside the loop
var tween=new TWEEN.Tween(mesh[i].scale).to({ x: 4, y: 4 },  1000);
if( i === 0 ) tween.onComplete(onCompleteCallback});
tween.start();
```

Comment: Thank you.You put the code that would be repeated 10 times.
(mesh length of the array).   ` for (var i in mesh){
 new TWEEN.Tween(mesh[i].scale)
    .to({ x: 4, y: 4 },  1000)
    .onComplete(function( console.log("the interpolation of all are finished")){

        })
    .start(); } `

then the message would appear 10 times to show. "the interpolation of all are finished".

I need to show the message once, when the interpolation of all meshes end.

Comment: You are the developper, you deduce that yourself from what you need. In your example the duration is the same for all the meshes, and if your callback is always the same, then of course no need to call it 10 times. Instead for example : `if ( i === 0 ) tween.onComplete( onCompleteCallback)` for example. If the durations are not the same, the `onCompleteCallback` could count each time it is called, and `if ( counter === mesh.length )`, they all have complete and you call another real complete function. Or whatever you can invent, up to you to define what best suits your project.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I tried the code and apparently does what I need. I have been busy for study and I could not realize that I really need. if a new question about it arises me, I can question again ?. I'm partial exams, and I was not able to practice this as wanted.